# Bounty help should not solely refer to answers when posting

Tags: feature-request, bounties, help-center

One sentence in the ["What is a bounty? How can I start one?" help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) seems to focus the attention for posting bounties as a result of unsatisfactory answers. However, bounties can be posted without any answer at all. My suggestion is to rephrase the misleading sentence:

> #### How do I start a bounty? When can I start a bounty?
>
> A bounty can be started on a question two days after the question was asked.
>
> To start a bounty, click on the "start a bounty" link at the bottom of an eligible question and allocate anywhere between 50 and 500 reputation, in 50-point increments. You can also choose from [a list of bounty reasons](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/) to help other users understand why you’re <strike>dissatisfied with any current answers to the question</strike> *posting the bounty*. If you need to describe something in more detail, there’s also optional, additional custom text that will be displayed with the bounty reason.

I don't think *any* refers to zero here.